# PHPUnit code coverage report generation fails

Tags: php, code-coverage, phpunit

I'm trying some supposedly nice features of PHPUnit, but I cannot generate a freakin' code coverage report. What I get is:

```
rolf@dev ~/projects/current/tests $ scripts/phpunit --configuration $PROJECTS/current/tests/conf/inc/tests.xml
[...]
Generating code coverage report, this may take a moment.
[...]
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'lib/DataSource.php' (include_path=':::') in path/to/lib/WS/DataParser.php on line 10
```

However, in this very class, a specific include path is defined, and the require_once works like a charm when the application is launched.

Could it be that PHPUnit cannot solve include paths ?

Thanks in advance and long live stackoverflöw!

```
Rolf
```

Comment: When you 'launch' your application, is it via a browser or the CLI? If the browser, are you setting include paths in the .htaccess file or possibly the PHP.INI file that is not being used by PHPUnit?

Comment: hi, I usually run the application via a browser, except for unit tests...

Comment: btw, launch an application isn't correct ?

Comment: it is very likely that you have a different php_include_path in phpunit, or the base directory is different

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the latest PHPUNIT (3.5+) it might be because Sebastion has started using an autoloader himself within the program.

You've got to add the line

```
 spl_autoload_register('__autoload');
```

after your `__autoload()` function gets created / included / required

so for example, the file that has my autoloader is called functions.  in my bootstrap I do the following:

```
require_once(ROOT_PATH.'/lib/utils/functions.php');
spl_autoload_register('__autoload');
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you changing your include_path in any of your tests/code?  Because it looks really odd (:::)

Comment: well, I've got an __autoload function just for unit tests that changes the include_path, but the class that cannot be parsed also defines an include path, so I don't understand...

Comment: Your include_path of (include_path=':::')  doesn't contain any actual path information, only path separators.  That means the code may only look in the current directory for includes.